# Find total frequency of number In Column

Tags: r

I am new on R. I want to ask, How to find frequency of each Number in Column, there are multiple numbers in column. i want to frequency of each number. I want just simple code. You can imagine that data set name is Oct-TT. Thanks

Comment: try `?table`  and then `table(df$col)`

Comment: i'm import a column from csv Named: Oct TT. and Column name DNIS.

Comment: install.packages(Hmisc); require(Hmisc); describe(Oct-TT) will provide a short an usefull summary of all variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
df <- as.data.frame(sample(10:20, 20,replace=T))
colnames(df) <- "Numbers"
View(df)

as.data.frame(table(df$Numbers))
```